# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I see a lot of these errors described at StackOverflow but none of the solutions work for me. It seems this Exception is thrown at many possible mistakes and does not really tell you anything. Steps to reproduce

1. Create a MvvmCross application with Visual Studio 2017
2. Open the FirstView.axml
3. Add a DropDownListView from the toolbox into the Designer
4. Run the application on a Samsun Galaxy S6 (Android 6.0.1)

Here's the View that fails:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                local:MvxBind="Text Hello" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                local:MvxBind="Text Hello" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dropDownListView1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I immediatly get the InflateException.

Here are a few snippets from the logcat which might give an indication:

```
03-16 14:50:35.621 20884 20884 I MonoDroid: UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:

03-16 14:50:35.641 20884 20884 I MonoDroid: Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView ---> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

03-16 14:50:35.641 20884 20884 I MonoDroid:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

And:

```
03-16 14:50:35.641 20884 20884 I MonoDroid:   --- End of managed Android.Views.InflateException stack trace ---

03-16 14:50:35.641 20884 20884 I MonoDroid: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView

03-16 14:50:35.641 20884 20884 I MonoDroid:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)

03-16 14:50:35.641 20884 20884 I MonoDroid:     at mvvmcross.binding.droid.views.MvxLayoutInflater_PrivateFactoryWrapper2.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
```

and:

```
03-16 14:50:35.651 20884 20884 I MonoDroid: UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:

03-16 14:50:35.651 20884 20884 I MonoDroid: Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView ---> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

03-16 14:50:35.651 20884 20884 I MonoDroid:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

03-16 14:50:35.651 20884 20884 I MonoDroid:   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <8c304e4006094a46a7950338a3b3cb5d>:0
```

I also see these lines frequently:

```
03-16 14:50:35.601 20884 20884 I AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.

03-16 14:50:35.611 20884 20884 W art     : Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

I've searched the project for app:theme but none found.

Comment: Which version of android are you targeting?

Comment: The problem was living too much in a XAML mindset. I should not use the DropDownListView but a spinner. What is very disorienting is the fact that the Toolbox is populated with a lot of components one can not use.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the error stacktrace:

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

Which means, that after parsing your `xml` framework tries to create a java object for class [`android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/DropDownListView.java) with constructor that accepts `Context` and `AttributeSet`, which, apparently, doesn't exist.

As long as it has one constructor with signature [`public DropDownListView(Context context, boolean hijackFocus)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/DropDownListView.java#85), I believe you have to create it through Java code in runtime.